# Bittorrent Imlementation - decode "peers" value in tracker response

Tags: c++, protocols, network-protocols, bittorrent

I am trying to decode the "peers" value in the tracker response using c++.

According to the bittorrent protocol:

> peers: (binary model) Instead of using the dictionary model described
>   above, the peers value may be a string consisting of multiples of 6
>   bytes. First 4 bytes are the IP address and last 2 bytes are the port
>   number. All in network (big endian) notation.

I have been trying so far this code:

```
void DecodePeers(OrderedMap<std::string, int> &map, const char * buffer)
{
    int counter = 0;

    char * peerIp = new char[5];
    char * portNum = new char[3];

    while (*(buffer + counter) != NULL)
    {

        for (int i = counter; i < counter + 4; i++)
        {
            *(peerIp + i - counter) = *(buffer + i);
        }

        counter += 4;

        *(peerIp + 4) = '\0';

        for (int i = counter; i < counter + 2; i++)
        {
            *(portNum + i - counter) = *(buffer + i);
        }

        counter += 2;

        *(portNum + 2) = '\0';

        std::string str(peerIp);
        int port = atoi(portNum);
        map.Insert(str, port);
    }
}
```

My problem is that this code gives me the port number: 7643488 which is obviously can't be a port number. Someone have an idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

> atoi(portNum);

That's for converting ascii / human-readable strings representing base 10 numbers into integer types. In other words you could only put the string `"00"` to `"99"` into 2 bytes. Port numbers are 0-65535, which is an uint16, which fits into 2 bytes as-is without any encoding.

All you need to do is to account for the byte order.